# How to expect dynamic count of elements in e2e tests using Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm currently writing some e2e tests for my humble Angular app with Protractor.

My app works fine, unit tests passes all, e2e used too... until this one:

**appE2ESpec.js**

```
describe('adding an item', function() {
  var items,
      addItemButton,
      startCount;

  beforeEach(function() {
    items = element.all(by.css('li.item'));
    addItemButton = element(by.id('addItemButton'));
    startCount = items.count();
  });

  it('should display a new item in list', function() {
    addItemButton.click();

    expect(items.count()).toEqual(startCount+1);
  });
});
```

This is how I would have written my test but,

**The problem is:** that items.count() returns a promise, *I know that*, but I can't manage to force Protractor to resolve it. So I get this:

```
Failures:

1) myApp adding an item should display a new item in list
  Message:
    Expected 6 to equal '[object Object]1'.
```

**What I've tried:**

```
items.count().then(function(count) {
  startCount = count;
  //console.log(startCount) --> "6" Perfect!
});
```

But got the same result at the end... I can't put the `expect` into the `then`, I thought about that too.

- I searched into Protractor GitHub repository issues, StackOverflow and Google AngularJs group.

**Appendix:**

`console.log(startCount)` outputs this :

```
{ then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }
```

I could have written `.toEqual(6)` but I don't want to rewrite my test each time I need to change my app startup state.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to resolve the promise and then do the assertion.

Protractor will resolve the promise that you pass to expect(), but it cannot add a number to a promise. You need to resolve the value of the promise first:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  ...
  items.count().then(function(originalCount) {
    startCount = originalCount;
  });
});

it('should display a new item in list', function() {
  ...
  expect(items.count()).toEqual(startCount+1);
});
```

Comment: You're my hero! Thank you ;) Hope that will help other people starting with Protractor :)

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem. They should create a method in protractor to resolve these promises. They shouldn't force programmers to use expect() just to resolve a promise. There will always be a case where you will need the value without the need to use expect()

Comment: @glepretre I am having the same issue but.. the solutions presented above is not working. I am getting "Expected 3 to equal undefined." error.

Comment: @glepretre I'm also having this problem and I'm getting the same outcome as Rahul

Answer (score 2):

While using `chai` for assertions there is `chai-as-promised` that allows to cope with promises in more readable way. To have it work you need first to declare:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
```

and then in the code:

```
// here is modified remaind of the code from the original question:
it('should display a new item in list', function() {
  addItemButton.click();

  expect(items.count()).should.eventually.equal(startCount+1);
});
```