# How to get the count of the number of child div element present inside a root div element in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, protractor

I am testing a web application project using Protractor . The few test cases which I have written is running fine but I am getting difficulties when I try to count the number of div elements present inside a parent div element, The structure of my div is given below

```
  <div class="page-kontact-main">
  <div class="buttons contact_page">
    <a href="http://mysite.se/om-oss/" class="btn btn-default button">Om oss</a>
    <a href="http://mysite.se/offert-3/" class="btn btn-default button">Offert</a>
    <a href="http://mysite.se/tjanster/" class="btn btn-default button">Våra Tjänster</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row kontact-title">
    <h2>Våra medarbetare</h2>
    <p>
      Test desc <span class="s47jd228h2" id="s47jd228h2_5">med</span> passion och engagemang för it &amp; system.  &nbsp;Skicka in din ansöka
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>

  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col206"></div>
    <div class="col206"></div>
    <div class="col206"></div>
    <div class="col206"></div>
    <div class="col206"> </div>
    <div class="col206"></div>
    <div class="col206"></div>
    <div class="col206"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have written the test case like this as given below but it is not running the error is expected undefined to equal 21.

```
it('Getting the count of contact names ', function() {
        driver.get("http://mysite.se/kontakt/");
        var element = driver.findElement(protractor.By.css('.clearfix .col206'));
        expect(element.length).toEqual(21);

    });
```

Thanks 
Utpal

Comment: Hi Utpal. Please provide a bit more html. The problem with this html is there may be other elements with the class name clear fix. Also you can use findelements method. If you can provide more html from the upper part of what ever html you have provided i can give the code.

Comment: @Vinay I have given more html code please look and suggest some wayout.

Comment: Could this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685161/how-to-expect-dynamic-count-of-elements-in-e2e-tests-using-protractor ? I used `element.all()` in the `beforeEach`.

Comment: @glepretre the part which I am testing is a non angular part so element.all is not working

Comment: "element is a helper function for finding and interacting with elements on the page you are testing" - from [Protractor - Getting Started](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md). It's a global variable, you should be able to use it to test a non angular part/page.

Comment: You can also try `WebElement.all`  if you prefer. I don't know if `FindElement.all` exists...

Comment: What if the sub div elements don't have classes? How can we count the number of child div elements in that situation?  Like this: <div class="row clearfix">
    <div >1</div> <div >2</div> <div >3</div> <div >4</div>  </div>

Answer (score 24):

You should use **element.all** and **count()** instead of **length**:

```
it('Getting the count of contact names ', function() {
    driver.get("http://mysite.se/kontakt/");
    var elements = element.all(protractor.By.css('.clearfix .col206'));
    expect(elements.count()).toEqual(21);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`$` and `$$` are equivalent to `element.all` and `by.css`, so you can use the following code

```
it('Getting the count of contact names ', function() {
    driver.get("http://mysite.se/kontakt/");
    var elements = $$('.clearfix .col206'));
    expect(elements.count()).toEqual(21);
});
```