# How to assign count of number of rows to another value which can be use later in the test cases in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

How to assign count of number of rows to another value which can be use later in the test cases in Protractor.

I have written following code but its not returning count value:

```
var rows = element.all(by.repeater('row in renderedRows'));
var row1 = rows.count().then(function(rowsn) { 
        return rowsn;
        console.log(rowsn);
    });
```

Now i want to use this count value in for loop

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685161/how-to-expect-dynamic-count-of-elements-in-e2e-tests-using-protractor/21686010#21686010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor functions generally return promises, not values.  So, you need to do your computation in a `then` or other code that resolves the promise.
You'll want to read [the Protractor Control Flow doc](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) and probably [the WebDriverJS control flow doc](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows)

In your case, some thing like:

```
var rowsPromise = element.all(by.repeater('row in renderedRows'));
rowsPromise.count().then(function(rowsn) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < rowsn; i++) {
            // do something with rowsPromise[i] (which is also a promise)
        }
    });
```